# greasemonkey sandbox and scope question

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables, greasemonkey

I am creating a GM script and had a question about how to set it up with as little global pollution as possible.

I have 1 main function which is available and a bunch of private function inside the main one. Something like this:

```
function main(a, b, c) {
    /* CODE */
    f1(a);
    /* CODE */
    f2(a + c);
    ...
    function f1(a) {
        /* CODE */
    }
    function f2(a) {
        /* CODE */
    }
}
```

I was wondering should I rather use `var f1 = function(a) {...}` or the way I have it?

Also should I use `function main(a, b, c)` or `var main = function(a, b, c)`

The only difference between the two that I can think of is if it will be parsed before running any code so I can write my code with my private functions out of the way. Are there any chanced of name conflicts either way?

Comment: In Greasemonkey, each script has its own sandbox (its own global scope). The only way to access/pollute the main page's global scope is by accessing `unsafeWindow`.

Comment: @Thai yeah but I plan on using this in other scripts too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering should I rather use var f1 = function(a) {...} or the way I have it?

The way you have it, `function f1(){}`, because then the function will have a name `f1` which is useful for debugging code.

> Also should I use function main(a, b, c) or var main = function(a, b, c)

you should use the name `main` if you plan to let other scripts use your script. The former method is better tho for the reason I gave above.

Maybe you want something like:

```
(function(){
   function f1() {} ;
   function f2() {};
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter between the two ways. Any name conflicts would likely arise either way. If you do `var f1 = function(a) {}` you'll need to define those at the top of your main function, before you try to call them.

```
var main = function(a, b, c) {
    var f1 = function(a) {
        /* CODE */
    };
    var f2 = function(a) {
        /* CODE */
    };
    /* CODE */
    f1(a);
    /* CODE */
    f2(a + c);
};
```